# How to extend partition size without losing data?

Tags: partition, gparted

How do I extend the size of `/dev/sda5` using the unallocated space on the top? I've tried using the `resize/move` option directly but can't do that because the partition is mounted and it can't be unmounted since it is the only partition. I tried `swap-off` and then increasing the size of swap. And it didn't work either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot in a live usb and extend the partition. While it should work fine, better have a backup. You cannot extend ext4 foward (to leading empty space) on-line.

Comment: 'You cannot extend ext4 foward (to leading empty space) on-line.' What does this mean?

Comment: You cannot extend it "left" when it is on-line/mounted. But you can extend it to the "right". Shrinking in either side is not supported when mounted. So you have to unmount it. But since it is your root partition, you have to use live usb (or another computer).